# Put another HDD in Ubuntu Server 10

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, backup

I am using Ubuntu Server 10 for LAMP and hosting sites.

I've added a second HDD for backups, but as the Server 10 runs without GUI, I don't know now how to access/configure backups to the second HDD without GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by "access" it you might find  [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mount-drive-from-command-line-ubuntu-linux/) useful.

You might also find information on ZFS interesting, which you can find  [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/175159/an-introduction-to-the-z-file-system-zfs-for-linux/)

You can use `sudo fdisk -l` to see if your drive is there.

EDIT: Use the above fdisk command to get the drive name. It will be something like /dev/sdb2 (for example).

Using the first link provided you can follow steps to mount your drive to a location and access it from there. From that point you can attach whatever you wish to it.

---

This page [Installing A New Hard Drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive) on the Ubuntu Community Help Wiki provides help for GUI and command line installation of a new Hard Drive

Comment: HINT to OP: enter *man fdisk* on the command line to get some help/info about the fdsik command

Comment: @lexu | Good point :)

Comment: Matthew i mean when i fizicly add second hdd how can i acces it where is location command example when i wont to configure that logs files from apache put on that another hdd i dont know command for mounting i dont know commands for access this second hdd ps extremly sory for my bad english

Comment: @dejanikus | I shall edit my answer to take this into account.